# Gson help with parse array - works without array but won't with array

Tags: java, android, gson

Can somebody help me with Gson parser. When I remove change from JSON and Result it works fine but with change it throws JsonParseException-Parse failed.

```
Result[] response = gson.fromJson(fileData.toString(), Result[].class);
```

I have classes like this

```
public class Result {
    public String start_time;
    public String end_time;
    public change[] change;
}
```

and

```
public class change {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

and Json string like

```
[
  {
        "start_time": "8:00",
        "end_time": "10:00",
        "change": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Sam"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "start_time": "9:00",
        "end_time": "15:00",
        "change": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Sam"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong ? Any idea why it won't work with array ?

Comment: You should try using a list instead: `List<ResultLine> response = gson.fromJson(fileData.toString(),
                        List<ResultLine>.class);`

Comment: However, you will need to use a type token thing in order to capture the generic type.

Comment: See: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener for generic help

Comment: Result vs ResultLine; Where is ResultLine defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been suggested, you need to use a list instead. Gson has pretty good documentation for using parametized types with the parser, you can read more about it [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html). Your code will end up looking like this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Result>>() {}.getType();
List<Result> results = gson.fromJson(reader, listType);
for (Result r : results) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is the same error. It isn't problem in array Result, it works when in json is not embedded array CHANGE. But it won't work when is in Json. That part I don't understand.

Comment: @Damir - not sure I follow your problem. I constructed a working test case based on what you posted above, you might want to expand your question with some of the code that is *not* working.

Comment: works perfectly in a very complex jsonArray with multiple arrays and objects inside it. Thank you very much.