# How to edit an item in a json file?

Tags: android, json

I have this structure that is generated by my application and I read in a listView:

```
[{
  "phone": "202020",
  "name": "Jhon",
  "id": 10,
  "age": 20
},
{
  "phone": "303030",
  "name": "Rose",
  "id": 11,
  "age": 22
}]
```

When I select an item in the listview, I open a screen form passing the values ​​of the clicked item.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String age = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.age)).getText().toString();
        String phone = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone)).getText().toString();

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_AGGE, age);
        in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE, phone);
        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

This screen opens when you click on the item is a form where I put the values ​​passed from the previous screen fields.

My question is: When you click save in this form, I have to get the new values ​​and update the json file. How to do this?

Ex: I want to change the record ID 22, which is the user Rose.

ADD MORE INFORMATION:

I already use the Gson to generate items.

Code to generate:

```
btnSalvar.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/ibbca/auditar.json");

    // to check if file exists before before it maybe will be created
    if (file.exists())
        fileExists = true;

    try{

        // create file or get access to file
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

        if (fileExists) // start new file as an array
            raf.seek(file.length() - 1);
        else { // start writing inside the bracket
            raf.writeBytes("[");
            raf.seek(file.length());
        }

        UserTestJson obj1 = new UserTestJson();
        obj1.setId(10);
        obj1.setName("Jhon");
        obj1.setAge(20);
        obj1.setPhone("202020");

        toJson(obj1);

        // end file
        raf.writeBytes("]");
        raf.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException f){
        f.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
});
```

And the Class UserTestJson, i created with get and seters for each variable.

Answer (score 5):

The Simplest way is, Just go to that json Object and set the desired value for the key.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(str);
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){

    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i); // get the josn object
    if(jsonObj.getString("name").equals("Rose")){ // compare for the key-value
        ((JSONObject)arr.get(i)).put("id", 22); // put the new value for the key
    }
    textview.setText(arr.toString());// display and verify your Json with updated value
}
```

Comment: Easy and simple and gets the job done :) One question I have is once a match is found how do i get all the data for that array?

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps a good time to switch to an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). 
I recommend to transfer the JSON into a custom model bean first:

```
class Person {
    long id;
    String phone, name, age;
}
```

Then you can use an JSON parser library like [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the array into a `List<Person>` and use this array to drive your list. (See [Gson help with parse array - works without array but won't with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932332/gson-help-with-parse-array-works-without-array-but-wont-with-array)) for an example on the parsing.

Finally, when you are ready to write back the data, simply re-generate the JSON from the array. This question got an example for that: [Trouble with Gson serializing an ArrayList of POJO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813434/trouble-with-gson-serializing-an-arraylist-of-pojos)

Pros:

- Once your JSON data model changes, only a small change in your model is needed to read the new format.
- You can use standard Java tools like ArrayList and POJOs

Cons:

- You will need to import GSON or equivalent into your project.

  - Also check this question: [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Hi Sebastian,

Thanks for helping.

I add more informations.  
  
My json file still enter the mobile users, and will be in this   format, as an array,
    `"phone": {
                         "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
                         "home": "00 000000"
                         "office": "00 000000"`
                     }.  
With the solution you sent, I can do this?

Comment: I added the phones in the array and it worked. But I still have doubts about how to get the item 22 and update it. How is the code snippet?

Comment: I encourage you to read this blog article list: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1679

Answer (score 0):

I cant find a direct way to do so.

But you can use this function to solve the problem first. See if there is other solution

```
private JSONObject setJSONVal(JSONObject jsonObject, String index, String value) throws JSONException{
   String jsonString = jsonObject.toString().trim();
   jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"" + index + "\":\"" + jsonObject.getString(index) + "\"", "\"" + index + "\":\"" + value + "\"");
   return new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```